# warning:'UIResponder' may not respond to '-manageTouches:'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

this is my program .

```
//Interface file.
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface reportView : UIView {

}
- (void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event;
@end

//ImplementationFile.
#import "reportView.h"

@implementation reportView

- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event{
    [self.nextResponder manageTouches:touches];
}
- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event{
    [self.nextResponder manageTouches:touches];
}
- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event{
    [self.nextResponder manageTouches:touches];
}
@end
```

I am getting the warning.
warning:'UIResponder' may not respond to '-manageTouches:'
I got 3 warnings as above.

I am getting the needed output correctly but how to resolve the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since your code looks exactly like listing 14.2 from [*iPhone in Action*](http://www.manning.com/callen/), did you remember to copy the code for `-manageTouches:` from listing 14.3 into your class?

Assuming that you did, the issue is that the `nextResponder` property points to an instance of `UIResponder`, which could be just about anything (your class, a window, some other OS-managed thing....), and the compiler doesn't know for sure that this particular responder implements a method `-manageTouches:`. Your options are basically to either live with the warning, or cast the value of `nextResponder` to your class. (FWIW, the bottom of page 247 mentions this.)

For that matter, *you* don't really know, at runtime, that the next responder will respond to that message. To be on the safe side, you might want to use `-respondsToSelector:` or `-isKindOfClass:` to validate that assumption.